# Stock increases by itself Magento 1.9.2.0

Tags: magento-1.9, product, stock

I have an issue on a `Magento 1.9.2.0` webshop. About 3 weeks ago products with a Stock of `0` automatically change to a Stock of `1` within half an hour.

As far as I know there have not been any changes to how Stock is calculated. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using any module or API to update stock automatically? If no then someone updated it manually.

Comment: No, all stock is managed manually.

Comment: Have you canceled any order with this item? By canceled I refer too to "created" new orders in backoffice, as that process cancels the original one

Comment: No, all orders are made by customers via the frontend.